# How to deserialize XML having prefix in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, namespaces

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ls:LeadResponse xmlns:ls="example.org/ls">
    <ls:status>OK</ls:status>
    <ls:code>approved</ls:code>
    <ls:message>posted</ls:message>
 </ls:LeadResponse>
```

It has the prefix `ls` everywhere.

I have done like this for deserialization

Model created:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LeadResponse",Namespace="example.org/ls")]
 public class LeadProviderResponse
 {
     [XmlElement(Namespace = "example.org/ls")]
     public string Status { get; set; }

     [XmlElement(Namespace = "example.org/ls")]
     public string Code { get; set; }

     [XmlElement(Namespace = "example.org/ls")]
     public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

and the code for deserialization

```
using var streamReader = new StringReader(xmlContent); 
using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(streamReader, null);    
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(LeadProviderResponse));
var result = (LeadProviderRespone)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

It is not able to deserialize correctly. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Casing:

```cs
[XmlElement(Namespace = "example.org/ls", ElementName = "status")]
public string Status { get; set; }

[XmlElement(Namespace = "example.org/ls", ElementName = "code")]
public string Code { get; set; }

[XmlElement(Namespace = "example.org/ls", ElementName = "message")]
public string Message { get; set; }
```

or (same result):

```cs
[XmlElement("status", Namespace = "example.org/ls")]
public string Status { get; set; }

[XmlElement("code", Namespace = "example.org/ls")]
public string Code { get; set; }

[XmlElement("message", Namespace = "example.org/ls")]
public string Message { get; set; }
```

Comment: oops..Nice catch. Thank you.